# Ошибка при подключении к MySql через EF в Net

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework

Пытаюсь подружить .Net, EF и MySql. Сделал консольное приложение, за основу взял примет отсюда:[MySQL в ASP.NET MVC](https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/23.php)

Но вот проблема: если модель состоит только из одной сущности, то все - ок, если из нескольких связанных сущностей, то в этом месте:

```
using(var db=new CustomerManagerContext())
        {
            db.Database.Create();
        }
```

Выбрасывается FormatException, с сообщением "входная строка имела не верный формат" Я пробовал разные варианты, в том числе и тот что указан на сайте Oraclа в качестве примера. Но результат такой же. В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо.

Comment: Так mysql или oracle?

Comment: MySQL Вот этот пример пытался тоже повторить, результат такой же: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: Вот [MySQL and C# Entity Framework “ProviderIncompatibleException”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51353695/mysql-and-c-sharp-entity-framework-providerincompatibleexception) решение проблемы.